# Repeat JavaScript AJAX request until status change

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, curl

I am using AJAX to make and retrieve an API call from PHP file and then using jQuery IF statements to display certain data.

The data returned come with a few different statuses, E.g.: "Ready", "In progress", "DNS" and "Error". Each status has a message that comes with it.

For one particular status, "In progress", I want to keep cycling through the JavaScript function until the status changes to something else.  If the status is "In progress", it can take up to 1 minute for it to change, so if possible, I would like to cycle through the JavaScript function in 5 second intervals.

I have included my jQuery below.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    //Stops the submit request
    $("#myAjaxRequestForm").submit(function(e){
           e.preventDefault();
    });

    //checks for the button click event
    $("#myButton").click(function(e){
           $("#ajaxResponse").empty();
            //get the form data and then serialize that
            dataString = $("#myAjaxRequestForm").serialize();

            //get the form data using another method
            var hostName = $("input#hostName").val();
            dataString = "host=" + hostName;

            //make the AJAX request, dataType is set to json
            //meaning we are expecting JSON data in response from the server
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
        url: "api.php",
                data: dataString,
                dataType: "json",

                //if received a response from the server
                success: function( response ){
                var data = response.status;
                    if ((data == 'READY' && response.endpoints[0].statusMessage == 'Ready' )) {
                    $("#ajaxResponse").append("<b>Status:</b> " + response.endpoints[0].statusMessage+ "<br>");
                    $("#ajaxResponse").append("<b>Host:</b> " + response.host+ "<br>");
                    $("#ajaxResponse").append("<b>Port:</b> " + response.port+ "<br>");
                    $("#ajaxResponse").append("<h3>Endpoint [0]</h3><b>Server Name:</b> " + response.endpoints[0].serverName+ "<br>");
                    $("#ajaxResponse").append("<b>IP Address:</b> " + response.endpoints[0].ipAddress+ "<br>");
                    $("#ajaxResponse").append("<b>Grade:</b> " + response.endpoints[0].grade+ "<br>");
                    $("#ajaxResponse").append("<h3>Endpoint [1]</h3><b>Server Name:</b> " + response.endpoints[1].serverName+ "<br>");
                    $("#ajaxResponse").append("<b>IP Address:</b> " + response.endpoints[1].ipAddress+ "<br>");
                    $("#ajaxResponse").append("<b>Grade:</b> " + response.endpoints[1].grade+ "<br>");
                    $("#ajaxResponse").append("<h3>Endpoint [2]</h3><b>Server Name:</b> " + response.endpoints[2].serverName+ "<br>");
                    $("#ajaxResponse").append("<b>IP Address:</b> " + response.endpoints[2].ipAddress+ "<br>");
                    $("#ajaxResponse").append("<b>Grade:</b> " + response.endpoints[2].grade+ "<br>");
                     }
                    else if ((data == 'READY' && response.endpoints[0].statusMessage != 'Ready')) {
                        $("#ajaxResponse").append("<b>Status: </b>" +response.endpoints[0].statusMessage+ "<br>");
                        $("#ajaxResponse").append("<b>Server Name: </b>" + response.endpoints[0].serverName+ "<br>");
                        $("#ajaxResponse").append("<b>IP Address: </b>" + response.endpoints[0].ipAddress+ "<br>");
                     }
                     else if (data == "DNS") {
                         $("#ajaxResponse").html("<div><b>No cached result found.<br><br>" +response.statusMessage+ "<br>..please wait a few mins and try again.</b></div>");
                     }
                     else if (data == "IN_PROGRESS") {
                         $("#ajaxResponse").html("<div><b>No cached result found.<br><br>" +response.endpoints[0].statusMessage+ "<br>..please wait a few mins and try again.</b></div>");
                     }
                     else if (data == "ERROR") {
                         $("#ajaxResponse").html("<div><b>Error.<br><br>" +response.statusMessage+ "<br></b></div>");
                     }
                     else {
                         $("#ajaxResponse").html("<div><b>error</b></div>");
                     }
                },

            });       
    });

});
```

Comment: what does `cycle through` mean? Keep making ajax requests?

Comment: yes, that's right. keep making ajax calls.

Comment: FYI- when you start repeating same selector multiple times, is best to cache it so a DOM search doesn't have to occur each time. DOM searches are expensive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the AJAX request to a function (e.g. doAjax()) so that you can call it as needed.  Call doAjax() when the button is clicked.  When the status returned is "In Progress", use setTimeout() to recursively call the same function after 5 seconds.

The AJAX request will be made roughly every 5 seconds until the status is something other than "In Progress".  (I say "roughly" because the AJAX request itself takes time and the 5 second delay starts AFTER the request is completed.)

Updated JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //Stops the submit request
    $("#myAjaxRequestForm").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    //checks for the button click event
    $("#myButton").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // Prevent default button click action
        doAjax();
    });

});

function doAjax() {
    //$("#ajaxResponse").empty(); Move this to reduce appearance of refreshing
    //get the form data and then serialize that
    dataString = $("#myAjaxRequestForm").serialize();

    //get the form data using another method
    var hostName = $("input#hostName").val();
    dataString = "host=" + hostName;

    //make the AJAX request, dataType is set to json
    //meaning we are expecting JSON data in response from the server
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "api.php",
        data: dataString,
        dataType: "json",

        //if received a response from the server
        success: function (response) {
            var data = response.status;
            if ((data == 'READY' && response.endpoints[0].statusMessage == 'Ready')) {
                $("#ajaxResponse").empty();
                $("#ajaxResponse").append("<b>Status:</b> " + response.endpoints[0].statusMessage + "<br>");
                $("#ajaxResponse").append("<b>Host:</b> " + response.host + "<br>");
                $("#ajaxResponse").append("<b>Port:</b> " + response.port + "<br>");
                $("#ajaxResponse").append("<h3>Endpoint [0]</h3><b>Server Name:</b> " + response.endpoints[0].serverName + "<br>");
                $("#ajaxResponse").append("<b>IP Address:</b> " + response.endpoints[0].ipAddress + "<br>");
                $("#ajaxResponse").append("<b>Grade:</b> " + response.endpoints[0].grade + "<br>");
                $("#ajaxResponse").append("<h3>Endpoint [1]</h3><b>Server Name:</b> " + response.endpoints[1].serverName + "<br>");
                $("#ajaxResponse").append("<b>IP Address:</b> " + response.endpoints[1].ipAddress + "<br>");
                $("#ajaxResponse").append("<b>Grade:</b> " + response.endpoints[1].grade + "<br>");
                $("#ajaxResponse").append("<h3>Endpoint [2]</h3><b>Server Name:</b> " + response.endpoints[2].serverName + "<br>");
                $("#ajaxResponse").append("<b>IP Address:</b> " + response.endpoints[2].ipAddress + "<br>");
                $("#ajaxResponse").append("<b>Grade:</b> " + response.endpoints[2].grade + "<br>");
            } else if ((data == 'READY' && response.endpoints[0].statusMessage != 'Ready')) {
                $("#ajaxResponse").empty();
                $("#ajaxResponse").append("<b>Status: </b>" + response.endpoints[0].statusMessage + "<br>");
                $("#ajaxResponse").append("<b>Server Name: </b>" + response.endpoints[0].serverName + "<br>");
                $("#ajaxResponse").append("<b>IP Address: </b>" + response.endpoints[0].ipAddress + "<br>");
            } else if (data == "DNS") {
                $("#ajaxResponse").html("<div><b>No cached result found.<br><br>" + response.statusMessage + "<br>..please wait a few mins and try again.</b></div>");
            } else if (data == "IN_PROGRESS") {
                $("#ajaxResponse").html("<div><b>No cached result found.<br><br>" + response.endpoints[0].statusMessage + "<br>..please wait a few mins and try again.</b></div>");
                // Call this function again after 5 seconds
                setTimeout(function () {
                    doAjax();
                }, 5000);
            } else if (data == "ERROR") {
                $("#ajaxResponse").html("<div><b>Error.<br><br>" + response.statusMessage + "<br></b></div>");
            } else {
                $("#ajaxResponse").html("<div><b>error</b></div>");
            }
        },

    });
}
```

Comment: works perfectly.. wondering though if there is way to achieve this without clearing the div but instead update the response.endpoints[0].statusMessage value.

Right now if i don't clear the div it will keep adding an extra line for every status change where as i just want the latest message

Comment: The response.endpoints[0].statusMessage should only be read - I can't envision why you would want to update it.  Which div do you want to update, and what do you want in it?

Comment: sorry, if i wasn't clear. I want to read it but as it cycles through the jquery i only want it to display the latest value. Right now, i am achieving this by clearing the div on each cycle. If i don't clear the div, the previous value will stay on the page. The only issue with how it is now is as the div is cleared the page looks like its refreshing. Not a huge problem but if i can find an alternate method instead of clearing the div it would look better.. the div in question is #ajaxResponse

Comment: See the updated answer.  It looks like it is refreshing because you clear the div before the AJAX request starts, and populate it after the request it done.  The requests take time, during which the div will appear blank.  I've updated my answer to only clear the div AFTER the request result is back, which should prevent any noticeable clearing of the div unless the actual status changes.